# How can we do a CSV import for my product on AppDrag?

Tags: csv, content-management-system, e-commerce

I recently migrated onto AppDrag and started using their e-Shop, which is very similar to Shopify.  But now I want to import my products without having to create them one by one.

Is there a way to do that by CSV?  I checked on the product page and can't seem to find the way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can import your products from CSV files. 
The import/export functionality is located on the shop dashboard not on the product page.